# Toggle div with same id as clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, jsfiddle

I am trying to toggle multiple divs independently.

It's currently working as it should, but not entirely.
What I try to achieve is to toggle a div which matches the clicked element - but I also want to be able to click on the element again and hide the matched div.

How can I achieve this? Feel free to use the jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/oczfefaa/9/

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("ul.menu li a").on("click", function(e) {
    $("div").addClass("hide");
    e.PreventDefault;
    var grabID = $(this).attr( "href" );
    $('div' + grabID).toggleClass("hide");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: you are adding `hide` class for all divs which are hiding all (including clicked div) and hence on toggleClass it will show the div though it was visible already. Try to add `hide` class to all divs except the clicked one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("ul.menu li a").on("click", function(e) { 
        e.PreventDefault; 
        var grabID = $(this).attr( "href" );                                
        $('div' + grabID).toggleClass("hide");
        $("div").not('div' + grabID).addClass("hide");//hide all div except clicked one.
    });

});
```

**[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/oczfefaa/12/)**

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much Bhushan! This solved my issue.

Comment: Hi @BhushanKawadkar How can I implement a if/else onto this piece of code? What I have is this so far: http://jsfiddle.net/oczfefaa/36/

Comment: sorry for late reply, but I did not get your question. Why do you want if / else, for what purpose?

Comment: Hi Bhushan, all okay :-) I need it to check if visible / if hidden. Gives me the option of doing something else when it's visible / hidden

Comment: You can make use if `is(':visible')` to check if element is visible or hidden or you can use `hasClass('hide')` to check if element has class or not. Check this [JSFIddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/oczfefaa/45/)

Comment: This will not work - if I press on one of the menus and click again to remove it they will all display.

Answer (score 0):

USE toggle instead og togleClass

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("ul.menu li a").on("click", function(e) { 
        $("div").addClass("hide");
        e.PreventDefault; 
        var grabID = $(this).attr( "href" );                                
        $('div' + grabID).toggle("hide");

    });
```

});

Comment: That is not the solution i am looking for unfortunately. It should only display one div at a time

Answer (score 0):

on every click u add class and toggle can only remove class...

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$("ul.menu li a").on("click", function(e) { 
    e.PreventDefault; 
    var grabID = $(this).attr( "href" );                                
    $('div' + grabID).toggle("hide");
});});
```